# How to make JQuery load on top of head tag before everything

Tags: jquery, javascript, wp-enqueue-script, headers

my website and plugins insert some jquery code between HTML tag and also whatever I do to insert jquery as a first script in the head section I can't get it to work

I tried

```
function use_jquery_from_google () {
    if (is_admin()) {
        return;
    }

    global $wp_scripts;
    if (isset($wp_scripts->registered['jquery']->ver)) {
        $ver = $wp_scripts->registered['jquery']->ver;
    } else {
        $ver = '3.1.4';
    }

    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/$ver/jquery.min.js", false, $ver);
}
```

also putting

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

directly into header.php and index.php of theme
but I got no success

so what can I do to make Jquery load really before everything
because editing third party plugin is really frustrating and time-consuming

```
UPDATE
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The function `wp_register_script` has a parameter called `$in_footer`. Setting this to false will add the script to the head.

`wp_register_script( string $handle, string|bool $src, array $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, bool $in_footer = false )`

In addition, if you deregister jquery, you can manually add the script in your head above `wp_head()`. This is generally not recommended.

Comment: Hello thanks when I add the script tag before wp_head() 
and load my main page 
there are like 15 more scripts before Jquery loading

I think its because of plugins 
I want to load before them

Comment: there should be a way

Comment: Other scripts may be relying on jQuery which is why it's still showing up. That's the `$deps` part of `wp_register_script()`. The appropriate way to work with this is to dequeue the default on the front-end of the site and then enqueue your own version to make it appear in the `wp_head()` first. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script

Comment: That being said, it sounds like you have a malicious plugin that's not following best practices. I would reach out to the developers and find out why.

Comment: yes exactly, they say their version fixed this but it doesnt , anyway is there a way or piece of code
to inject jquery before everything because when I view page source jquery is at the top over everything but when DOM loads it goes down and other script shows first, Im looking for a fix to override this

Comment: Without digging in to the code, I'm not sure.